# How can I set values from user input in a class and use them in a second class?

Tags: python, user-input

I am working on a python code that has 2 options. Make calculations for distance and area from user input or make the calculations from default point values.
For default point values, I got the code working. Nevertheless, I cannot get it to work for when user inputs the points. I currently read the inputs fine, but I cannot get to use them on the 2nd and 3rd class (Polyline and Polygon)

```
import math

#Point class
class Point():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def setXY(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#Class instantiation
p1 = Point()
p2 = Point()
p3 = Point()

val = 0

print("\n----Please select from the following options:----")
print("Enter 1 to set your point coordinates")
print("Enter 2 to use default point coordinates\n")

val = int(input("Enter your value: "))
if val == 1:
    #Set point values for P1
    p1_x = int(input("Enter x value for P1: "))
    p1_y = int(input("Enter y value for P1: "))
    #Set point values for P2
    p2_x = int(input("Enter x value for P2: "))
    p2_y = int(input("Enter y value for P2: "))
    #Set point values for P3
    p3_x = int(input("Enter x value for P3: "))
    p3_y = int(input("Enter y value for P3: "))
    #Set point values
    p1.setXY(p1_x,p1_y)
    p2.setXY(p2_x,p2_y)
    p3.setXY(p3_x,p3_y)
    #Print points values
    print("Location of point P1 is: (",p1.x,",",p1.y,")")
    print("Location of point P2 is: (",p2.x,",",p2.y,")")
    print("Location of point P3 is: (",p3.x,",",p3.y,")")
    print("\n")

    #Polyline class
    class Polyline():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0
        def setXY(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    #getLength() method for distance calculation
    #Distance formula: root square of[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]
        def getLength(self, p):
            return math.sqrt((self.x-p.x)**2+(self.y-p.y)**2)

    #Class instantiation
    p1 = Polyline()
    p2 = Polyline()
    p3 = Polyline()
    #Set point values
    print("Location of point P1 is: (",p1.x,",",p1.y,")")
    p1.setXY(p1.x,p1.y)
    p2.setXY(p2.x,p2.y)
    p3.setXY(p3.x,p3.y)
    #Creating variables and setting their value to their respective distance
    resultPoint1_2 = p1.getLength(p2)
    resultPoint2_3 = p2.getLength(p3)
    resultPoint1_3 = p1.getLength(p3)
    #Print distance values
    print("Length of the perimeter from P1 to P2 is: ", resultPoint1_2)
    print("Length of the perimeter from P2 to P3 is: ", resultPoint2_3)
    print("Length of the perimeter from P1 to P3 is: ", resultPoint1_3)
    print("\n")

    #Polygon class
    class Polygon():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0
        def setXY(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    #getLength() method for distance calculation
    #Distance formula: root square of[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]
        def getLength(self, p):
            return math.sqrt((self.x-p.x)**2+(self.y-p.y)**2)

    #Class instantiation
    p1 = Polygon()
    p2 = Polygon()
    p3 = Polygon()
    #Set point values
    p1.setXY(p1_x,p1_y)
    p2.setXY(p2_x,p2_y)
    p3.setXY(p3_x,p3_y)
    #Creating variables and setting their value to their respective distance
    resultPoint1_2 = p1.getLength(p2)
    resultPoint2_3 = p2.getLength(p3)
    resultPoint1_3 = p1.getLength(p3)
    #Creating perimeter variable and setting its value according to the formula
    #Perimeter formula for 3 points polygon: length1 + length2 + length3
    perimeter = resultPoint1_2 + resultPoint2_3 + resultPoint1_3
    #Print perimeter value
    print("Perimeter of the polygon is: ", perimeter)
    print("\n")
```

Current output when input 3 for x and y values on all points:

```
Location of point P1 is: ( 3 , 3 )
Location of point P2 is: ( 3 , 3 )
Location of point P3 is: ( 3 , 3 )


Location of point P1 is: ( 0 , 0 )
Length of the perimeter from P1 to P2 is:  0.0
Length of the perimeter from P2 to P3 is:  0.0
Length of the perimeter from P1 to P3 is:  0.0


Perimeter of the polygon is:  0.0
```

As you can see, the 2nd and 3er class are not utilizing the values set on the first class.

Comment: You're using the same variables `p1, p2, p3` for the `Point` and `Polyline` instances. So when you write `p1.setXY(p1.x,p1.y)`, `p1.x` refers to the `Polyline`, not the `Point`.

Comment: Did you really intend to define the `Polyline` and `Polygon` classes inside the `if` statement? Usually functions and classes are defined at top-level.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I did. I understand your point, but for this project I found it necessary.

Comment: @Barmar, would you please share in code the solution suggested?

Comment: Hard to imagine there ever being a good reason for defining functions and classes in a branched statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use different variables for the points, polylines, and polygons. Otherwise, when you write something like

```
p1.setXY(p1.x, p1.y)
```

this is getting `p1.x` and `p1.y` from the Polygon that you're trying to update, not the Point that you created earlier.

In the code below, `p1, p2, p3` are Points, `pl1, pl2, pl3` are Polylines, and `pg1, pg2, pg3` are Polygons.

```
import math

#Point class
class Point():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def setXY(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#Class instantiation
p1 = Point()
p2 = Point()
p3 = Point()

val = 0

print("\n----Please select from the following options:----")
print("Enter 1 to set your point coordinates")
print("Enter 2 to use default point coordinates\n")

val = int(input("Enter your value: "))
if val == 1:
    #Set point values for P1
    p1_x = int(input("Enter x value for P1: "))
    p1_y = int(input("Enter y value for P1: "))
    #Set point values for P2
    p2_x = int(input("Enter x value for P2: "))
    p2_y = int(input("Enter y value for P2: "))
    #Set point values for P3
    p3_x = int(input("Enter x value for P3: "))
    p3_y = int(input("Enter y value for P3: "))
    #Set point values
    p1.setXY(p1_x,p1_y)
    p2.setXY(p2_x,p2_y)
    p3.setXY(p3_x,p3_y)
    #Print points values
    print("Location of point P1 is: (",p1.x,",",p1.y,")")
    print("Location of point P2 is: (",p2.x,",",p2.y,")")
    print("Location of point P3 is: (",p3.x,",",p3.y,")")
    print("\n")

    #Polyline class
    class Polyline():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0
        def setXY(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    #getLength() method for distance calculation
    #Distance formula: root square of[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]
        def getLength(self, p):
            return math.sqrt((self.x-p.x)**2+(self.y-p.y)**2)

    #Class instantiation
    pl1 = Polyline()
    pl2 = Polyline()
    pl3 = Polyline()
    #Set point values
    print("Location of point P1 is: (",p1.x,",",p1.y,")")
    pl1.setXY(p1.x,p1.y)
    pl2.setXY(p2.x,p2.y)
    pl3.setXY(p3.x,p3.y)
    #Creating variables and setting their value to their respective distance
    resultPoint1_2 = pl1.getLength(p2)
    resultPoint2_3 = pl2.getLength(p3)
    resultPoint1_3 = pl1.getLength(p3)
    #Print distance values
    print("Length of the perimeter from P1 to P2 is: ", resultPoint1_2)
    print("Length of the perimeter from P2 to P3 is: ", resultPoint2_3)
    print("Length of the perimeter from P1 to P3 is: ", resultPoint1_3)
    print("\n")

    #Polygon class
    class Polygon():
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0
        def setXY(self,x,y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

    #getLength() method for distance calculation
    #Distance formula: root square of[(x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2]
        def getLength(self, p):
            return math.sqrt((self.x-p.x)**2+(self.y-p.y)**2)

    #Class instantiation
    pg1 = Polygon()
    pg2 = Polygon()
    pg3 = Polygon()
    #Set point values
    pg1.setXY(p1_x,p1_y)
    pg2.setXY(p2_x,p2_y)
    pg3.setXY(p3_x,p3_y)
    #Creating variables and setting their value to their respective distance
    resultPoint1_2 = pg1.getLength(p2)
    resultPoint2_3 = pg2.getLength(p3)
    resultPoint1_3 = pg1.getLength(p3)
    #Creating perimeter variable and setting its value according to the formula
    #Perimeter formula for 3 points polygon: length1 + length2 + length3
    perimeter = resultPoint1_2 + resultPoint2_3 + resultPoint1_3
    #Print perimeter value
    print("Perimeter of the polygon is: ", perimeter)
    print("\n")
```